# Extra Volumes appearing after using MyDefrag

Tags: windows-xp, filesystems, defragment

After using MyDefrag, when I start the defrag again, two new drives have appeared - with very odd names.

They are both named the same thing:

```
\\?\Volume{WhatLooksLikeAGUID}
```

Note the Guid (and hence the drive names) are both the same - any idea whats going on here?

Thanks.

OS: Windows XP Pro SP2.

Answer (score 0):

most like these are hidden partitions created by the manufacturer, e.g. system recovery, EFI (ASUS netbooks), MediaDirect Partition (Dell only)

Comment: But the first time I used MyDefrag (before I had started a defragmentation), they were not there.  They only appeared after I had run the defrag a couple of times.

Comment: sorry, i'm not familiar with JK/MyDefrag, these partitions should remain hdden.